# Drawing Concentric Circles, appearing one at a time, Java

Tags: java, animation, graphics

I'm trying to draw concentric circles that appear one at a time, from smallest to largest outward. I'm wanting to give an illusion of the circle expanding, by adding an additional circle to the outside of the existing outer circle each time the loop executes. At the moment all the circles appear at the same time when I run my program. Please help, I have no idea how to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void drawCircles(Graphics g) {
    int radius = 10;
    int x = 0;
    while(x <= 10) {
        int z = radius / 2;
        g.drawOval(100 - z, 100 - z, radius, radius);
          x++;
          radius = radius + 10;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pause the program between circle draws add a call to Thread.sleep(long millis) where millis is the number of milliseconds that you want to pause.

```
public static void drawCircles(Graphics g) {
  int radius = 10;
  int x = 0;
  while(x <= 10) {
    int z = radius / 2;
    g.drawOval(100 - z, 100 - z, radius, radius);              
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    x++;
    radius = radius + 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give the illusion of expanding circle. Your algorithm should remove the old circle by wiping off the canvas `or` for example drawing the background again so that it seems that you have cleared the old circle,before drawing the new one.

So, say if my background was a gray color box, i will draw that before I draw my new circle.

```
g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
g.fillRect(0,0,BACKGROUND_SIDE_X, BACKGROUND_SIDE_Y);
g.drawOval(100 - z, 100 - z, radius, radius);
```